# Google reporting ISO 8601 error in JSON-LD

Tags: google-search-console, json-ld, iso8601

I am for the first time trying to create a JSON-LD snippet for an event.

Google's Webmaster Tools (URL inspection) is reporting an error in the event date/time:

> Date/time not in ISO 8601 format in field "startDate"

My date is:

```
"startDate": "2023-09-16T15:30-16:30",
```

Google's example date at https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/event is:

```
"startDate": "2025-07-21T19:00-05:00",
```

Apart from the actual values, I can see no difference and https://json-ld.org/playground/ is not showing any problems.

In case it helps, the full snippet (removing links that stackoverflow thinks are spam) is:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Event",
      "name": "Think Big",
      "startDate": "2023-09-16T15:30-16:30",
      "endDate": "2023-10-21T15:30-16:30",
      "eventStatus": "https://schema.org/EventEventScheduled",
      "eventAttendanceMode": "https://schema.org/OfflineEventAttendanceMode",
      "location": {
        "@type": "Place",
        "name": "Methodist Church",
        "address": {
          "@type": "PostalAddress",
          "streetAddress": "Old Town",
          "addressLocality": "Stratford-Upon-Avon",
          "postalCode": "CV37 6BG",
          "addressRegion": "Warwickshire",
          "addressCountry": "GB"
        }
      },
      "image": [
        "[removed]"
       ],
      "description": "Confidence boosting workshops for the Shyer Child (for ages 8-9)",
      "organizer": {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "The Beehive, Stratford-Upon-Avon",
        "url": "[removed]"
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: `-05:00` is the time zone difference. it can not be *16:30*

Comment: Ah. I'm assuming it should be the ending time of the event.

But thanks for the very prompt reply, it will save me a lot of head scratching (and maybe help others too)